# Listing IBM Cloud Resources using ResourceControllerV2 and pagination issues

Tags: python, ibm-cloud

I'm using the Python ibm-cloud-sdk in an attempt to iterate all resources in a particular IBM Cloud account. My trouble has been that pagination doesn't appear to "work for me". When I pass in the "next_url" I still get the same list coming back from the call.

Here is my test code. I successfully print many of my COS instances, but I only seem to be able to print the first page....maybe I've been looking at this too long and just missed something obvious...anyone have any clue why I can't retrieve the next page?

```
try:
    ####### authenticate and set the service url
    auth = IAMAuthenticator(RESOURCE_CONTROLLER_APIKEY)
    service = ResourceControllerV2(authenticator=auth)
    service.set_service_url(RESOURCE_CONTROLLER_URL)

    ####### Retrieve the resource instance listing
    r = service.list_resource_instances().get_result()
    ####### get the row count and resources list
    rows_count = r['rows_count']
    resources = r['resources']

    while rows_count > 0:
        print('Number of rows_count {}'.format(rows_count))

        next_url = r['next_url']

        for i, resource in enumerate(resources):
            type = resource['id'].split(':')[4]
            if type == 'cloud-object-storage':
                instance_name = resource['name']
                instance_id = resource['guid']
                crn = resource['crn']
                print('Found instance id : name - {} : {}'.format(instance_id, instance_name))

        ############### this is SUPPOSED to get the next page
        r = service.list_resource_instances(start=next_url).get_result()
        rows_count = r['rows_count']
        resources = r['resources']

except Exception as e:
    Error = 'Error : {}'.format(e)
    print(Error)
    exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the [API documentation for listing resource instances](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-controller/resource-controller?code=python#list-resource-instances), the value of **next_url** includes the URL path and the **start** parameter including its token for start.

To retrieve the next page, you would only need to pass in the parameter **start** with the token as value. IMHO this is not ideal.

I typically do not use the SDK, but a simply Python request. Then, I can use the endpoint (base) URI + next_url as full URI.

If you stick with the SDK, use [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) to extract the query parameter. Not tested, but something like:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse,parse_qs
o=urlparse(next_url)
q=parse_qs(o.query)
r = service.list_resource_instances(start=q['start'][0]).get_result()
```

Comment: In the python core library that serves as an enabling layer for our Python SDKs, we have a function named `get_query_param()` that can be used to retrieve the `start` query parameter from a request URL.   You can find an example of its use [here](https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-python-sdk/blob/e4ceb30ab0b02dd7820ab334217a83033ebde6af/ibm_platform_services/resource_controller_v2.py#L3964), which also happens to be the implementation of the `ResourceInstancesPager` class which is a convenience class for retrieving paginated results from the `list_resource_instances()` operation.

Answer (score 0):

Could you use the Search API for listing the resources in your account rather than the resource controller? The search index is set up for exactly that operation, whereas paginating results from the resource controller seems much more brute force.

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/search#search

Answer (score 0):

This answer is a little late, but the Resource Controller service within the Platform Services Python SDK has been updated with some additional convenience functionality related to pagination.

Specifically, instead of invoking the `list_resource_instances()` operation directly, you could instantiate and use the ResourceInstancesPager class to retrieve items a page at a time while avoiding the details of retrieving the "start" parameter value from the "next_url" response property, etc.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-python-sdk/blob/e4ceb30ab0b02dd7820ab334217a83033ebde6af/examples/test_resource_controller_v2_examples.py#L165).

Comment: Good to know that the SDK has finally improved. Looking at the sample code, it has the same number of lines as my direct solution, but requires more dependencies and has a larger footprint. Any other features in the SDK that warrants moving away from using the API and Python requests?